# How do I install Social Network Importer for NodeXL for Excel 2013 if NodeXL does not appear in my Program Files?

Tags: excel, excel-addins

When installing the Social Network Importer for NodeXL in Excel 2013 (specifically on 64bit systems), the installation notes prompt to unzip the Social Network Importer files into a folder located at C:\Program Files\Social Media Research Foundation\NodeXL Excel Template\PlugIns but NodeXL Excel Template 2014 does not create this folder in all installations.

Where should I install the Social Network Importer files to use them with NodeXL Excel Template 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed NodeXL 2014, I realised that it did not create the required folder in my Program Files directory but instead installed itself in the following location:

~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

So I did the following:

1. Unzipped the Social Network Importer files to that location
2. Open NodeXL and navigate to the NodeXL -> Data -> Import -> Import Options tab and entered that full directory address in the empty box and clicked 'OK' !

[image: NodeXL file path]
 3. Closed NodeXL then reopened it

This successfully added the social importer options.

It looks like you could unzip those files anywhere as long as you point NodeXL to the correct directory.